# Creating a Table and insertion data into database not working properly with mysql and java jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

#### ConnectionClass:

Here I used `stm.execute` but I'm not getting an error. I also used `executeUpdate` but I'm also getting an error.

```
package com.company;
import java.sql.*;
class ConnectionClass {
    private static Connection con = null;
    private static Statement stm = null;
    private  static  ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    public void createConnection() {
      try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "root");
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    public  void createTable() {
      String Table_Name = "BOOK";
      try {
        stm = con.createStatement();
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = con.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs =  dbm.getTables(null, null, Table_Name, null);
        if (rs.next()) {
          System.out.println("Table" + Table_Name + "Already created");
        } else {
          String sql = "CREATE TABLE" + Table_Name + "(ID VARCHAR(200), title VARCHAR(200),author varchar(100),publisher varchar(100)";
          stm.executeLargeUpdate(sql);
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    public ConnectionClass() {
      createConnection();
      createTable();
    }
}
```

#### MainClass:

Here I think the main class is working properly.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      ConnectionClass connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    }
}
```

#### ERROR:

[image]

Comment: Idk why the question was down voted, but i have up voted it to even the vote.

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using?

Comment: Also, please don't use images for error messages, post the exception stacktrace as text.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your query. You current SQL Query:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE" + Table_Name + "(ID VARCHAR(200), title VARCHAR(200),author varchar(100),publisher(100)";
```

Corrected SQL Query:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE" + Table_Name + "(ID VARCHAR(200), title VARCHAR(200),author varchar(100),publisher varchar(100)";
```

(You are asking mysql to create a column `publisher`, but where's the datatype? Simply specify the datatype and it will work.)

#### EDIT:

So, finally wrapping up this question, let's have a look at what Ora Docs have to say about this:

executeLargeUpdate:

```
default long executeLargeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException
```

Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.
This method should be used when the returned row count may exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE - `A constant holding the maximum value an int can have, 2^31-1`.

Note:This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.

> The default implementation will throw UnsupportedOperationException. This method is introduced since JDK 1.8

Also note the above point as stated in the docs. The default implementation is to throw an UnsupportedOperationException. This means that different JDBC drivers can have different implementations of `Statement` class. They can either implement it or leave it unimplemented, and if you invoke the method in 2nd case, the method will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`, as stated in the docs.

By checking the oracle docs for this [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeLargeUpdate-java.lang.String-), you can get more information about it. So the possibility could be that the driver version you are using is not supporting this method, so please update tot eh latest version of this driver and try it out.

Comment: It made it to `executeLargeUpdate` because that is what will execute the statement (and if it had been implemented, that would have resulted in a syntax error).

Comment: But sill this problem occur:                                                                   at com.company.ConnectionClass.setBookTable(ConnectionClass.java:69)
 at com.company.ConnectionClass.<init>(ConnectionClass.java:85)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:13)

Answer (score 0):

The method `executeLargeUpdate` was added in Java 8 / JDBC 4.2 and judging by the error it has not been implemented in the MySQL Connector/J version you are using.

The solution is simple: don't use any of the `Large` methods in the API, and instead use `executeUpdate`, or - better in the case of DML - `execute`. Alternatively, update to a newer version of MySQL Connector/J, as `executeLargeUpdate` is implemented in newer versions of MySQL Connector/J (eg 5.1.46, but at least 5.1.37 (the version that added support)).

You will also need to address the syntax error [pointed out by Adil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49963171/466862).